# composer require phpoffice/phpspreadsheet don't work

Tags: php, symfony, php-7

initially, I needed a library that will help me upload data to Excel, found this library and then there was a problem

i try to install **composer require phpoffice/phpspreadsheet**
but i have problem

```
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - The requested PHP extension ext-spltype * is missing from your system. Install or enable PHP's spltype extension.


Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json to its original content.
```

I don’t understand where the error comes from, because there is a dependency "ext-spltype": "*" in my composer.json

this is my composer.json

```
{
    "type": "project",
    "license": "proprietary",
    "require": {
        "php": "^7.2.5",
        "ext-ctype": "*",
        "ext-iconv": "*",
        "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "^5.5",
        "symfony/asset": "5.1.*",
        "symfony/console": "5.1.*",
        "symfony/dotenv": "5.1.*",
        "symfony/expression-language": "5.1.*",
        "symfony/flex": "^1.3.1",
        "symfony/form": "5.1.*",
        "symfony/framework-bundle": "5.1.*",
        "symfony/http-client": "5.1.*",
        "symfony/intl": "5.1.*",
        "symfony/mailer": "5.1.*",
        "symfony/mime": "5.1.*",
        "symfony/monolog-bundle": "^3.1",
        "symfony/notifier": "5.1.*",
        "symfony/orm-pack": "^1.0",
        "symfony/process": "5.1.*",
        "symfony/security-bundle": "5.1.*",
        "symfony/serializer-pack": "*",
        "symfony/string": "5.1.*",
        "symfony/translation": "5.1.*",
        "symfony/twig-pack": "^1.0",
        "symfony/validator": "5.1.*",
        "symfony/web-link": "5.1.*",
        "symfony/yaml": "5.1.*",
      "ext-spltype": "*"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "symfony/debug-pack": "*",
        "symfony/maker-bundle": "^1.19",
        "symfony/profiler-pack": "*",
        "symfony/test-pack": "*"
    },
    "config": {
        "optimize-autoloader": true,
        "preferred-install": {
            "*": "dist"
        },
        "sort-packages": true
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "src/"
        }
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\Tests\\": "tests/"
        }
    },
    "replace": {
        "paragonie/random_compat": "2.*",
        "symfony/polyfill-ctype": "*",
        "symfony/polyfill-iconv": "*",
        "symfony/polyfill-php72": "*",
        "symfony/polyfill-php71": "*",
        "symfony/polyfill-php70": "*",
        "symfony/polyfill-php56": "*"
    },
    "scripts": {
        "auto-scripts": {
            "cache:clear": "symfony-cmd",
            "assets:install %PUBLIC_DIR%": "symfony-cmd"
        },
        "post-install-cmd": [
            "@auto-scripts"
        ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
            "@auto-scripts"
        ]
    },
    "conflict": {
        "symfony/symfony": "*"
    },
    "extra": {
        "symfony": {
            "allow-contrib": false,
            "require": "5.1.*"
        }
    }
}
```

i also try to install  sudo pecl install SPL_Types , but i have error

Comment: We need to know which OS are you using in order to help you.

Comment: @Vanlesk , i use Linux - Ubuntu

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm using Ubuntu 18.04 with Apache. Using the script from here works.

```
sudo apt-get install libpcre3-dev php5-dev php-pear -y
sudo pecl install SPL_Types
echo extension=spl_types.so | sudo tee /etc/php5/mods-available/spl_types.ini
sudo php5enmod spl_types
sudo service apache2 reload
```

Comment: i writed, that 
i also try to install sudo pecl install SPL_Types , but i have error

Comment: i use 7.2 version

Answer (score 0):

This is a PHP PECL extension and it's installation is managed out of composer:
https://www.php.net/manual/en/spl-types.installation.php

Composer is just checking if it's present and fails if it's not.

Comment: i tried this way
sudo pecl install SPL_Types
WARNING: channel "pecl.php.net" has updated its protocols, use "pecl channel-update pecl.php.net" to update
downloading SPL_Types-0.4.0.tgz ...
Starting to download SPL_Types-0.4.0.tgz (8,388 bytes)
.....done: 8,388 bytes
6 source files, building
running: phpize
sh: 1: phpize: not found
ERROR: `phpize' failed

Comment: @Таня try to run `sudo apt-get install php7.2-dev` before that (in order to install phpize)

Answer (score 0):

i delete  "ext-spltype": "*" from composer.json and it work now